# How to set the Startup Project in VB6?

Tags: vb6, ide

Can you set the startup Project in the Visual Basic 6 IDE?

I looked all through the Settings and can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave and OneDayWhen are correct in saying that you need to right click the desired project in the IDE and select Set as Start Up when you have multiple projects loaded and you want to choose which one is executed.

> Anyone know how I can set the VB6 IDE
>   to load either the last project loaded
>   or change the default one loaded?

Copy the Icon change the target to something like

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE" "D:\MyProjects\MyOneProject\trunk\MyOneProject.vbp"

Change Startup In to D:\MyProjects\MyOneProject\trunk

I found it more just to change the StartupIn to my Master Project Directory rather than have icons for specific project. Like D:\MyProjects

Rob Conley

P.S. In case you are wondering on why you would ever select a non-EXE project as startup. You do this at times when you are debugging a non-EXE. When you startup a non-EXE you have several options. Among them you can fire up a application,or have sit there until something calls it. Useful when you are debugging a Active DLL or Control and using Excel or another 3rd party software that you don't have the source too.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have multiple projects in a Group e.g. a dll and a dependent exe and you want to set the exe as the 'start up' project. Do so this, select the exe project in the Project Explorer, right click and choose 'Set as Start Up' from the context menu. The 'start up' project's name will be shown as bold text in the Project Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a "startup Project" settting in VB6, but you can select the "Startup Object" by opening the Project menu, choosing the last menu item ("X properties", where X is the name of your project), and then selecting the General tab in the Project Properties window. The selector you seek is in the upper-right corner.